# Session key is None in django?

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I have been trying to use cookie sessions to save user's data, I have used session successfully in my previous applications but this time it's not working properly

I know that in order to get the value of the session key the session has to modified or saved.

So what  I used to do before is make a mixin and used to call that on the view I needed the session key, The case for me here was to grab the session key and the save that value in an instance field but the session key is None or if I change my code to what I have written at the bottom it creates a new session key at every request

Here's the mixin I used in my previous applications and it worked fine

```
class SessionMixin:
    def get_session(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        session = self.request.session
        if not session.get('has_session'):
            session["has_session"] = True
            return self.__class__.get(self,request,*args,**kwargs)

class MyView(SessionMixin,generic.View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
           super().get_session(self,request,*args,**kwargs)
           print(self.request.session.session_key,"Gives me none")
           # rest of the code goes here
```

My setting for session cookies

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 604800  
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
```

Here's what I tried too but it just created a session key on every single request.

```
class SessionMixin:
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        session = self.request.session
        if not session.session_key:
            session.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `get` method in  is not calling the `get_session(...)` method. Also, you can do the implementation like this:

```
class SessionMixin:
    def get_session(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if not request.session.session_key:
            request.session.create()
        return request

class MyView(SessionMixin,generic.View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
       self.get_session(request)
       print(request.session.session_key)
       return super().get(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

I am using `create()` method instead of `save()`. Because it is designed to create new session. More information can be found in [**documenation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views).

Comment: Sorry I know i have called the super().get but in my code i have actually called the super().get_session,this is a typo i have fixed it

Comment: did this answer solved the multiple session key created?

Comment: nah the session_key is still none

Comment: Also I'm having another question if you could help in that.

Comment: Here's the link of that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929560/how-does-derived-class-arguments-work-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you in one of my apps.
I solved the problem with this code.
You will no longer have session_key None.

```
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
       request.session['cached_session_key'] = request.session.session_key
```