# How does derived class arguments work in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I am having difficulty understanding one thing in Python.I have been coding in Python from a very long time but there's is something that just struck me today which i struggle to understand

So the situation goes like this

I have a mixin and a view

```
class Mixin:
    def get_session(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        print(self) #should be the instance passed
        print(request) #should be the request object passed but it's also an instance

class View:
     def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
         self.get_session(self,request,*args,*kwargs)
         pass
```

Why is the request argument the instance of the Class View, It should be request.Please help me clarify these concepts.

Comment: You're passing `self` explicitly as the first argument of `get_session`. That means it goes into the `request` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `self` explicitly as the first argument of `get_session`. That means it goes into the `request` parameter.

```
self.get_session(self,request,*args,*kwargs)
  ^               ^        ^^^^^^^^^^
(self)        (request)    (the rest)
```

I think you mean:

```
self.get_session(request, *args, **kwargs)
```